# Magento 2 add Sort By Best Sellers Option on category products litsing page

Tags: magento-2.0, magento-2.1

I am trying to add new custom sort by option on categories products listing page along with other existing options like Name , Position and Price.

To test my functionality i am directory doing changes to Magento core files Just for testing purpose , so that once it will work , i will create a separate custom module for that.

I have modified `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php` and i have added

```php
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ["test" => 'sales_order_item'],
    'main_table.entity_id = test.product_id',
    ['qty_ordered'=>'SUM(test.qty_ordered)'])
    ->group('main_table.entity_id')
    ->order('qty_ordered ASC');
```

Just after this line. `$collection = $this->_getProductCollection();`

In function `_beforeToHtml()`

But i am getting error as

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
'main_table.entity_id' in 'on clause'
```

Can anybody please help , where i am wrong and is there any better method to complimenting sort by best sellers option in Magento 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Here is an easy clean way to achieve this without overriding Magento core.
Create ***NameSpace\ModuleName\etc\frontend\di.xml*** file with current configuration:

```
<!-- Adding Sort by Bestsellers functionality -->
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
    <plugin name="before_set_collection" type="NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Sorting\Bestsellers" />
</type>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
    <plugin name="after_get_available_orders" type="NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Sorting\Bestsellers" />
</type>
```

Then create plugin class ***NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Sorting\Bestsellers.php***:

```
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Sorting;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;

class Bestsellers 
{
/**
* Bestsellers sorting attribute
*/
const BESTSELLERS_SORT_BY = 'bestsellers';

/**
 * @param Config $subject
 * @param $result
 * @return array
 */
public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(Config $subject, $result)
{
    return array_merge($result, [self::BESTSELLERS_SORT_BY => __('Bestsellers')]);
}

/**
 * @param Toolbar $subject
 * @param Collection $collection
 */
public function beforeSetCollection(Toolbar $subject, Collection $collection)
{
    if ($subject->getCurrentOrder() == self::BESTSELLERS_SORT_BY) {
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            'sales_order_item',
            'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id',
            array('qty_ordered'=>'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)'))
            ->group('e.entity_id')
            ->order('qty_ordered '.$subject->getCurrentDirection());
//->limit(5);//you can also limit products here.
    }
}
}
```

And enjoy =)

Comment: this technique works perfectly on Magento 2.3 , thank you very much.  
edit : but the loading time is then multiplied by ~20 !!!

Comment: This is not working for me.They get total collection not get only best seller.

Comment: This code was working perfectly in 2.2.9 but it completely made our site inaccessible after upgrading to 2.2.10. The query was overloading the database. According to Magento support, SQL queries building logic has changed in 2.2.10 but I still have no idea on how I can refactor it for 2.2.10.

Comment: Facing query overloading problem in the database issue on Magento 2.3.3.

Comment: This has 2 issues,
1. Page load problem
2.Also collection has same results, not filtering the best seller items

Comment: perfect answer ! +1 made my day!!! :)

Answer (score 5):

Finally i have completed it like this , may be it will help someone else

First i have added these 2 lines in **Company\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml** to update the core blocks

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Company\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config" type="Company\Module\Model\Config"/>
```

Then created Config Model

**Company\Module\Model\Config** with below script

```
class Config extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
{
    public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
       $options = ['bestseller' => __('Best seller')];
        foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute */
            $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
        }

       return $options;
    }
}
```

The Created a block

**Company\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar** with below script

```
class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="bestseller")
        {
              $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( 
                'sales_order_item', 
                'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id', 
                array('qty_ordered'=>'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)')) 
                ->group('e.entity_id') 
                ->order('qty_ordered '.$this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
        }

        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCurrentDirectionReverse() {
            if ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc') {
                return 'desc';
            } elseif ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc') {
                return 'asc';
            } else {
                return $this->getCurrentDirection();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: its works fine but, its removed position sort by option.

Comment: You don't need to create config.php just create a new attribute and set yes for used in sorting at product listing. It will not remove position sort by option.

Comment: @Dinesh Saini , I have overrided toolbar block like you said / suggested  but  sort by option is missing in search page .  apart from this anything still missing?

Comment: Hi, I am getting error "Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'qty_ordered ' in 'order clause'" while using this code. Please help with the solution.

Comment: It works well but I no longer have pagination for this list option..   :(

Comment: @Dinesh Saini, this has 2 issues, Page load and Pagination disappear

Answer (score 1):

i hope you we get pagination issue due to getsize count wrong. whenever you use group by query then call getSize function means it will give first record data so it will give wrong count. for this before embed group by query. you should call getSize function. so it will set before execute group by query.

code should like this

```
if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="bestseller")
        {
getSize()//called before group by function.
              $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( 
                'sales_order_item', 
                'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id', 
                array('qty_ordered'=>'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)')) 
                ->group('e.entity_id') 
                ->order('qty_ordered '.$this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me.
Create your di.xml file  /app/code/your_vendor\your_module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="Vendor_module::addCustomSortOptions" type="your_vendor\your_module\Plugin\Model\Config" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="Vendor_module::implementCustomSortOptions" type="your_vendor\your_module\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    </type>
</config>
```

create the config.php file /app/code/your_vendor/your_module/Plugin/Model

```
<?php
namespace your_vendor\your_module\Plugin\Model;

class Config
{
/**
 * Adding custom options and changing labels
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
 * @param [] $options
 * @return []
 */
public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
{
    //New sorting options
    $options['best_selling'] = __('Best Seller');
   

    return $options;
}
}
?>
```

Add the toolbar.php file inside your plugin
/app/code/your_vendor/your_module/Plugin/Product/ProductList

```
<?php
namespace your_vendor\your_module\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
/**
* Plugin
*
* @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
* @param \Closure $proceed
* @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
* @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
*/
public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $collection
) {
    $this->_collection = $collection;
    $currentOrder = $toolbar->getCurrentOrder();
    $currentDirection = $toolbar->getCurrentDirection();
    $result = $proceed($collection);

    if ($currentOrder) {
        switch ($currentOrder) {
        case 'best_selling':
              $this->_collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                'sales_order_item',
                'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id',
                array('qty_ordered'=>'(select sum(soi.qty_ordered) from sales_order_item soi where soi.product_id = e.entity_id)'))->distinct(true)
                ->order('qty_ordered '.$currentDirection);
                //echo $subject->getCollection()->getSelect();die;
                break;


        default:        
            $this->_collection
                ->setOrder($currentOrder, $currentDirection);
        break;

        }
    }
    //var_dump((string) $this->_collection->getSelect()); You can use this to get a list of all the available sort fields
    return $result;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The drawback of using `sales_order_item.qty_ordered` is lifetime sales, i.e. products with high recent sales will be in bottom of page.

I suggest create new index table, with product_id, SUM(qty_ordered) during last 30 days and sort by these values. Plus add second sorting factor by adding date.

[image]

Comment: What interface are these screenshots from?