# Sort by Product Ordered

Tags: magento2, admin

We need to be able to sort by product. Is it possible to create a report or view that allows a list of all the customers who ordered a specific product?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/135888/69 Should help as it's around Best Sellers which is pretty much the same, however you can adjust the SQL query to what you are looking to achieve. ...and welcome to MageStackExchange!