# How to sort product by best seller Magento 2.1 without changing in core file

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, best-seller

I want to get product Collection sort by bestseller product.

How to achieve  this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 add Sort By Best Sellers Option on category products litsing page](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135871/magento-2-add-sort-by-best-sellers-option-on-category-products-litsing-page)