# Magento 2 Sort by New Products and Most View Product

Tags: magento2, new-products

I am using this [Magento 2 add Sort By Best Sellers Option on category products litsing page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135871/magento-2-add-sort-by-best-sellers-option-on-category-products-litsing-page) for **Best Seller Products** i want to same  **New Products** and **Most View Product**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Company\Module\Model\Config

```
public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
        $options = ['bestseller' => __('Best Seller'), 'newest' => __('Newest'), 'mostviewed' => __('Most Viewed')];
        foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute)
        {
            /* @var $attribute \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute */
            $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
        }

        return $options;
    }
```

Company\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar

```
public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        // bestseller code

        if($this->getCurrentOrder() == "newest")
        {
            $collection->getSelect()
                ->order('created_at ' . $this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
        }

        if($this->getCurrentOrder() == "mostviewed")
        {
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                'report_event',
                'e.entity_id = report_event.object_id',
                array('view_count' => 'COUNT(report_event.event_id)'))
                ->group('e.entity_id')
                ->order('view_count ' . $this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
        }

        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if($limit)
        {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if($this->getCurrentOrder())
        {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting error "Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'view_count ' in 'order clause'" while use this code. Please help with the solution.

Comment: Am too facing this issue. Did you find any solution for this issue? @UditGupta

Answer (score -1):

If we need to get the most viewed product through SQL you have to just run this script in SQL and you will get the most view product in Magento-2

```
SELECT COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) AS `views`, `e`.* FROM `report_event` AS `report_table_views` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND e.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (report_table_views.event_type_id = 1) GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` HAVING (COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) > 0) ORDER BY `views` DESC
```

please comment if you will get any issues.

Answer (score -1):

**[Improved Sorting](https://marketplace.magento.com/invigoratesystems-module-improvedsorting.html)** extension provides the same functionality to sort by newest and most viewed products.