# How can I add "Sort by newest" and set it as default?

Tags: magento2.4, sort

I'd like to add custom sort option "Sort by newest" using `created_at` system attribute and I'd like to set it as default, from the backend `Stores->Catalog->Storefront->Product Listing Sort by`.

I overrode `\module-catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php` in my module with something like this:

```
/**
 * Add sort order option created_at to frontend
 */
public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    $options
) {
    $options['created_at'] = __('New');
    return $options;
}
```

Then I overrode `module-catalog\Model\Config.php` with:

```
/**
 * Set collection to pager
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
 * @return $this
 */
 public function setCollection($collection) {
    $this->_collection = $collection;
    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }

    // switch between sort order options
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        // create custom query for created_at option
        switch ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            case 'created_at':
                if ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc') {
                    $this->_collection
                        ->getSelect()
                        ->order('e.created_at DESC');
                } elseif ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc') {
                    $this->_collection
                        ->getSelect()
                        ->order('e.created_at ASC');           
                }
                break;
            default:
                $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
                break;
        }
    }

    // echo '<pre>';
    // var_dump($this->getCurrentOrder());
    // var_dump((string) $this->_collection->getSelect());
    // die;

    return $this;        
}
```

and it works but I'm not able to set it as default option and I don't know how I can add the option in the backend.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want as default right?

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to add newest, most popular, etc to sorting. I've tried various plugins but since update to Magento 2.4 and ElasticSearch default I can't get many to work. Did you compile your solution into a module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made a similar change, hooking into admin configurations in addition to `Magento\Catalog\Model\Config`:

1. Default sort configuration in Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Storefront > Product Listing Sort by.
   It uses `Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\ListSort` model for sorting.
2. Category level Available Product Listing Sort By, Default Product Listing Sort By.
   Source model here - `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Sortby`.

This way, admin has full control over default options, and can change settings globally of per category.

As a convenience, we slightly normalized above source models to always use results from `getAttributeUsedForSortByArray`,
that we already made a plugin over.

```
<!-- Use getAttributeUsedForSortByArray to include all plugins from there -->
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\ListSort" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\ListSource"/>
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Sortby" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Sortby"/>

<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
    <!-- Append custom sort options to $options -->
    <plugin name="vendor_module" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config" />
</type>
```

\Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\ListSource:

```
class ListSource extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\ListSort
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        foreach ($this->_getCatalogConfig()->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray() as $code => $label) {
            $options[] = ['label' => __($label), 'value' => $code];
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Vendor\Module\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Sortby:

```
class Sortby extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Sortby
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $options = [];
        foreach ($this->_getCatalogConfig()->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray() as $code => $label) {
            $options[] = ['label' => __($label), 'value' => $code];
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After some debugging, I found proper solution for Magento 2.4!

3. To get `created_at` EAV attribute to Elasticsearch index, this attribute needs to be marked as indexable.

See:

- \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\DataProvider::getSearchableAttributes
- \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection::addToIndexFilter

This attribute is visible=0, so it's not possible to do from admin panel, so we need to make a migration script:

app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/ChangeCreatedAtSearchable.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class ChangeCreatedAtSearchable implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * ChangePriceAttributeDefaultScope constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'created_at',
            'is_searchable',
            true
        );
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

4. Lastly, by default all attributes are declared as `text` in Elasticsearch, and sorting doesn't work for them.

We need to change `created_at` field declaration to "keyword".

di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper">
    <!-- Sets `created_at` type keyword to enable sorting -->
    <plugin name="vendor_module" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\AdditionalFieldMapper" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapperProxy">
    <!-- Sets `created_at` type keyword to enable sorting -->
    <plugin name="vendor_module" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\AdditionalFieldMapper" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

Same plugin declared for multiple adapters, this is because in Magento 2.3 some of them used for different Elasticsearch adapters. Keeping just in case.

```
use Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\Product\FieldProvider\FieldType\ConverterInterface;

class AdditionalFieldMapper
{
    /**
     * Sets `created_at` type keyword to enable sorting
     *
     * @param \Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapperProxy $subject
     * @param array $allAttributes
     * @return array
     * @see \Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper::getAllAttributesTypes
     */
    public function afterGetAllAttributesTypes($subject, array $allAttributes)
    {
        $allAttributes['created_at']['type'] = ConverterInterface::INTERNAL_DATA_TYPE_KEYWORD;

        return $allAttributes;
    }
}
```

Works for me after catalogsearch reindex :)

Comment: Thanks but I get this error `Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\ListSource does not exist` but it exists in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Config/Source/ListSource.php`

Comment: Ok, I forgot to indicate the namespace over the class declaration and now the `Newest` option is shown on the backend but if I set it as the default one I cannot see anymore a product on every category and subcategory page. They are empty.

Comment: Even if I don't set it as the default one but I choose it from the frontend category pages, then category pages don't show any products.

Comment: @KaMZaTa, my code handles admin options, and I presumed that your existing toolbar customization would handle the selection, my bad.

Comment: Do you know how to customize correctly the toolbar? I thought it was working too but it seems it doesn’t.

Comment: I replaced the `created_at` attribute hooking with `entity_id` and now it seems to work. Probably, using `created_at` attribute, it shows just the products with a set date for `New from date` and `New to date` fields (I don't have them now). So, now, using `entity_id`, it sorts the products regardless those 2 fields. I think the correct behavior should be listing before all products with the created_at field and then the remaining with the `entity_id` filed. What do you think?

Comment: Actually I have an inkling about why it doesn't work with created_at. Magento adds created_at sort to Elasticsearch sort query, which doesn't have this field in index, and Elasticsearch throws an exception in Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection::_renderFiltersBefore.

Comment: I think this workaround should work:
1. plugin Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper::afterMap - add `created_at` to index object
2. plugin Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapperProxy::afterGetAllAttributesTypes - set `created_at` data type, for example "keyword" so that it can be sortable
Don't have time to test right now, but I used this approach to add custom fields to ES index and sort.
P.S. Magento automatically adds entity_id sort in Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection::_beforeLoad

Comment: You could be right since I tried to set `New from date` and `New to date` fields in a sample product but using `created_at` didn't show anything anyway. However I didn't get exactly how I could implement your theory. Could you please edit your answer to include these details?

Comment: @KaMZaTa, updated :)

Comment: Thanks but this bonds the `Newest` feature to the Elasticsearch, don't this? Every time I'll update Elasticsearch it could break this feature, right? Using `entity_id` instead doesn't give this risk but the sort could be sometimes incorrect since it's based on insert time. Am I wrong? Anyway, great job.

Comment: I receive this error `Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data\ChangeCreatedAtSearchable' not found in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Patch/PatchRegistry.php on line 141`.

Comment: IN Magento 2.4 Elasticsearch is the only search adapter, MySQL was dropped. So I believe this change is fairly robust. I'll add namespace classname to migration example.
Actually, if you choose to sort by entity_id I don't see why it's inconsistent. It's a unique identifier, unlike created_at in my example.

Comment: Thanks @RomanKabanov this worked great for 2.4.5-p1, however, it's sorting Oldest->Newest for category pages. Sorting is working correctly Newest->Oldest for search results. Do you have an idea for a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to go with reference links:

[Magento 2 Sort by New Products and Most View Product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200100/magento-2-sort-by-new-products-and-most-view-product)

https://www.sparsh-technologies.com/magento-extensions/magento-2-advanced-sorting-extension

https://github.com/nitishd/magento-moresort

https://github.com/zekinah/magento2-AdvancedSortby

https://github.com/vvasiloud/SortByDate-Magento2

Please let me know if the above links will not work for you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but the 1°, 3°, and the 5° didn't work for me while the 2° and the 4° seem to be a little bit invasive (I didn't try them) because they add a new entire section in the backend instead of adding that simple Newest sort option.

Comment: Yes, correct, My suggestion is just take a require logic or code from module and use it in your module, hope this will work.