# new product first - magento 2

Tags: magento2

can i sort by date, i.e. the new product is displayed first!
[image]

I just can't find where to set it!

Comment: Take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321776/how-can-i-add-sort-by-newest-and-set-it-as-default

Comment: is there no way without having to do something to the code?