# Magento 2 : Sort By block is missing after override the toolbar for search page?

Tags: magento-2.1, php, toolbar

I want to add custom sort by options , I have override the toolbar block as follows

My di.xml file as

```
<preference for="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Custom\Product\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    <preference for="\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config" type="Custom\Product\Model\Config"/>
```

My toolbar.php block file as

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Product\Block\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {      

        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
         $bestseller = $this->getRequest()->getParam('best_seller');
        if($bestseller){
            $this->_collection->getSelect()->join( 
                'sales_order_item', 
                'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id', 
                array('qty_ordered'=>'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)')) 
                ->group('e.entity_id') 
                ->order('qty_ordered desc');
        }

        $onair = $this->getRequest()->getParam('onair');
        if($onair){
            $this->_collection->getSelect()->join( 
                'broadcast_program_mgmnt', 
                'e.sku = broadcast_program_mgmnt.sku_main AND broadcast_program_mgmnt.isProgramExposureStart=1') 
                ->group('e.entity_id') 
                ->order('broadcast_program_mgmnt.sku_main desc');
        }

        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="position")
        {
              $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('cat_index.position '.$this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
        }
        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="low")
        {
              $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('e.price asc');
        }
        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="high")
        {
              $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('e.price desc');
        }
        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="bestseller")
        {
              $this->_collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( 
                'sales_order_item', 
                'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id', 
                array('qty_ordered'=>'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)')) 
                ->group('e.entity_id') 
                ->order('qty_ordered '.$this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
        }
        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="new")
        {
             $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('e.created_at '.$this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
        }
        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="sort")
        {            
            $this->_collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( 
                'rating_option_vote_aggregated', 
                'e.entity_id = rating_option_vote_aggregated.entity_pk_value', 
                array('vote_count'=>'SUM(rating_option_vote_aggregated.vote_count)')) 
                ->group('e.entity_id') 
                ->order('vote_count '.$this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
        }
        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="onair")
        {            
            $this->_collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( 
                'broadcast_program_mgmnt', 
                'e.sku = broadcast_program_mgmnt.sku_main AND broadcast_program_mgmnt.isProgramExposureStart=1') 
                ->group('e.entity_id') 
                ->order('broadcast_program_mgmnt.sku_main '.$this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
        }
        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=="discount")
        {            
            $this->_collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( 
                'catalogrule_product_price', 
                'e.entity_id = catalogrule_product_price.product_id AND '
                    . 'catalogrule_product_price.latest_start_date <= now() AND catalogrule_product_price.earliest_end_date >= now()') 
                ->group('e.entity_id') 
                ->order('catalogrule_product_price.product_id '.$this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCurrentDirectionReverse() {
            if ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc') {
                return 'desc';
            } elseif ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc') {
                return 'asc';
            } else {
                return $this->getCurrentDirection();
            }
        }

}
?>
```

The override file calling but Sort by drop down in search page is not displaying.

In listpage sort by block is showing but in search page is missing.

here is the search page image

[image]

here is list page image

[image]

Please help me to solve this, thank you in advance .

Comment: Finally got the solution but after applying the sort options getting blank page.

Here is the solution

Need to mention in layout file as follows
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
          <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml</argument>
          </action>
        </referenceBlock>

Comment: could you please answer this question in good format? In which layout file and what to add? Because I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Please see my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/230983/59595.
I hope it helps!